# Problemas no Login em jQuery

Tags: php, html, sql, login

Criei um login para minha aplicação, mas estou com problema no retorno.
O painel de usuário e senha envia a requisição ao php login (que acessa o banco). O retorno é um 'OK', que deveria ser validado no código abaixo:

```
  $('#btnLogin').click(function(){
    var login = $('#inputEmail').val();
    var senha = $('#inputPassword').val();
    $.post('_class/login.php',{inputEmail: login, inputPassword: senha}, function(data){
      console.log(data);
        if(data === 'OK'){
        location.reload();
      }else{
          $('#myModal').modal('show');
      }
    });
  });
```

Problema: o retorno esta aceitando o 'OK', mas não abre a tela home e ainda retorna a mensagem de login incorreto (myModal). Depois de apagar a mensagem de erro, ao recarregar a página (F5), o sistema abre a home. Como eu posso arrumar isso?

edição-----------------

eduardo, estou usando os códigos:
html

```js
 $('#btnLogin').click(function(){

    var login = $('#inputEmail').val();

    var senha = $('#inputPassword').val();

    
    $.post('_class/login.php',{inputEmail: login, inputPassword: senha}, function(data){

      //console.log(data);
      var response = $.trim(data);
          
     if(data === 'OK'){

        location.reload(true);
                
      }else{
       
       $('#myModal').modal('show');

      }

    });

  });
```

```html
  <form class="vertical-form" id="new_user" action="_class/login.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><legend>

    Acesso

  </legend>

  <input placeholder="Email" label="false" type="text" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" />

  <input placeholder="Senha" label="false" autocomplete="off" type="password" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" />

  <input type="button" id="btnLogin" name="commit" value="Acessar" />

  <!-- <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Acessar" /> -->

  <p><a style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Esqueceu sua senha?</a></p>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu já passei por isso e resolvi assim:

Do lado PHP:

```html
echo trim('OK');
```

Do lado JavaScript:

```js
var response = $.trim(data);

if(data === 'OK'){
    location.reload();
}else{
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Eu usei `trim()` dos dois lados, porque em modo estrito (`use strict;`) o JavaScript pede que seja usado `===` para fazer comparações, e nesse caso todos os bytes são comparados e se um estiver fora do lugar, retorna `false`.

Usando `trim()` eu consigo eliminar os bytes extras, causados por espaços em branco por exemplo.

Comment: eduardo, vlw a dica...mas ainda estou na mesma. Tentei usar a sugestão nas duas pontas. O código esta com problema no reload da página....acho eu. Continua mostrando o aviso de login inválido, mas se apertar F5...carrega a home.

Comment: Ah, se esse é o problema, tenta usar `history.go(0);` ou `window.location.href = window.location.href;` no lugar de `location.reload();`. Se preferir, tenta colocar um  true no `location.reload( true );`. Vê aí e atualiza seu post com suas tentativas.

Comment: cara, editei e inclui os códigos html e javascript...continuo na mesma...testei todas as opções que vc passou